# Searching string value for different formats from the Database Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I want to search and get data from the database once users search the value. Example User type `BCD-1254` from the view. In Database, the record could be saved in different ways like, `WPBCD-1254`, `BCD1254`, `WPBCD-1254` , `BCD-1254` , `bcd-1254` , ''bcd1254`` wise. So from the controller, I want to select all the records related to the search value.

I did this way, but from the search results, not all records are getting from the database table. How can I search for it from the controller?

```
List<ServiceHistoryVM> History = new List<ServiceHistoryVM>();

            var Services = (from a in db.AppRequest
                            join v in db.VehicleService on a.Id equals v.Req_Id
                            join vd in db.VehicleServiceDetails on v.Id equals vd.VehicleService_Id
                            where vd.Vehicle_No.ToLower() == VehicleNumber.ToLower()
                            select new ServiceHistoryVM
                            {
                                Date = a.Created_Date,
                                MileageToDate = vd.Current_Service_Mileage.ToString(),
                                MileageToLast = vd.Last_Service_Mileage.ToString()
                            }
                            ).ToList();
```

Comment: You would need to write a code specific to your needs, no easy ways around that. For your case you need something like 
vd.Vehicle_No.ToLower().Replace("-", "").Contains(VehicleNumber.ToLower().Replace("-", ""))
in the where clause.
Just keep in mind that your database engine might not be able to translate that and the query will be slow

Comment: Alternatively, if you are just developing your project and can freely change database, ElasticSearch has a feature called Fuzzy Query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html
which might be of use for you

Comment: @Hubert Thanks for the Fuzzy Query I will try that. Also, I did a change to the where like ``where vd.Vehicle_No.Contains(VehicleNumber)`` and did return the tested results. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to answer your question.
If your main focus is to get or return all matching records that contain what is entered or similar to what is entered then you will need a simple algorithm to tweak your search criteria.

```
char[] sch =new char[]{'-','/','*'};
string[] searchwords = searchcriteria.Split(sch);

string keyword="";
foreach(var word in searchwords){
  keyword=keyword + word;
}
```

Your linq lambda query will now look like below:

```
var searchresult = FROM s in db.Table WHERE s.FIELD.Contains(searchcriteria) || s.FIELD.Contains(keyword) SELECT s;
```

This is a scenario where you may need to replace many characters in the search with empty space.
The searchcriteria is the variable for the search string.